# How to set per line limit in a text area and also wrap the text to the next line when it exceeds the per line limit in java script

Tags: javascript, java

I have a text area in JSP , I want to limit per line characters and when a person types more than the limit then it should automatically take us to the next line . Please help me

Comment: Set the width of the `textarea` in `em` units and make sure that word wrapping is turned on.

Comment: I want to set a limit per line which we would be less than the width value, eg . I just want 45 characters per line on the text area having a width of 100px . If the text is more that 45 characters the entire word should wrap to next line